# Javascript IDE that forces strict typing, semicolons, and validates code like JSLint (or: that adds the advantages of a compiler to Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ide, node.js

I'm looking for ways to make developing big server sided JavaScript (I'm working with Node.js) projects a whole lot easier.

Basically, the problems I'm facing with JavaScript is that I'm not being warned when I make a syntax error, or when I mix different kinds of object types in the same arrays/variables etc.

I was using Haxe to solve these problems (as it gave me back a compiler), however the problem with not writing directly in JavaScript is that one has to create bindings for every existing JavaScript library.

Maybe there is an IDE that can help me write errorless code?

I'm basically wanting to hear more about your experience with making development of big JavaScript projects easier.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All of Jetbrains IDEs can do that, e.g.: http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/

Comment: Including strict typing? Eg. var someInt[Int]; as variable declaration?

Comment: +1 - There is only so much checks that an IDE can do for a dynamic language. It's not the IDE's fault, but has to do with the language itself. However, JetBrain's IDEs do a pretty good job at deducing as much of the information as possible including inspecting the return types from each function to figure out the type of a variable as it travels through these functions, and several other optimizations.

Comment: I'm not saying it's the IDEs fault, but it would be a good feature.

Comment: I don't think it can do strict type checking, but it can definitely be as helpful as JSLint (and even more IMO)

Comment: Strict typing is support in builds 102.114+ http://blogs.jetbrains.com/webide/2011/01/use-strict-from-ecmascript-5-is-supported-in-webstorm-phpstorm/

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to have Visual Studio 2010 then you could install the [JSLint extension](http://jslint4vs2010.codeplex.com/) and configure it to enforce validation at build-time.